# replacing null values from in map with some other value

Tags: enums, maps, elixir

I have a map

```
exchange_accounts = %{"BSE" => "yes", "MCX" => "", "NSE" => ""}
```

I need to check for only empty values in this given map.
if I find any key with empty value/null it should be replaced by some other value. Only null values should be changed, other values should be same

this is what i have tried.I tried doing it using for loop its working but everytime it takes a new map and  i also need to store all replaced values in new map because i need to insert it in database.

suppose `client_id = "ASHA14"`

```
for {k, v} <- exchange_accounts, v == "",
  do: Map.replace!(exchange_accounts, k, client_id)
```

the result should be a map

```
%{"BSE" => "yes", "MCX" => "ASHA14", "NSE" => "ASHA14"}
```

but everytime its iterating over loop and forming a newmap

```
[%{"BSE" => "ASHA14", "MCX" => "", "NSE" => ""}
 %{"BSE" => "", "MCX" => "ASHA14", "NSE" => ""}
 %{"BSE" => "", "MCX" => "", "NSE" => "ASHA14"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so what you're doing is looping over `exchange_accounts` with a filter `v == ""`.
It will create a new list with value from `Map.replace!(exchange_accounts, k, client_id)`

```
iex()> for {k, v} <- exchange_accounts, v == "", do: Map.replace!(exchange_accounts, k, client_id)
[
  %{"BSE" => "yes", "MCX" => "ASHA14", "NSE" => ""},
  %{"BSE" => "yes", "MCX" => "", "NSE" => "ASHA14"}
]
```

What i think it should be:

```
 Enum.reduce(exchange_accounts, %{}, fn {k, v}, acc ->
   if v == "" || v == nil, do: Map.put(acc, k, client_id),
   else: Map.put(acc, k, v)
 end)


iex()>
%{"BSE" => "yes", "MCX" => "ASHA14", "NSE" => "ASHA14"}
```

Comment: oh yeah..you are correct. Thank you so much its working.

Answer (score 1):

You were nearly there; while [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) surely works, the more concise solution with [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension (using `into:` keyword parameter to produce a map) would be:

```rb
for {k, v} <- %{"BSE" => "yes", "MCX" => "", "NSE" => ""},
  do: {k, (if is_nil(v) or v == "", do: "SUBST", else: v)},
  into: %{}
#⇒ %{"BSE" => "yes", "MCX" => "SUBST", "NSE" => "SUBST"}
```

The thing is `for/1` just skips entries not passing any of conditions, while you need to keep them intact.